# due date for tax filling when recently moved abroad

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I was US resident alien for the three past years (no Green card; had an H1B visa), i.e. 2017, 2018 and 2019. In December 2019 I moved permanently back to my native country. We 're now (February 2020) entering the tax season and I am due to file taxes for 2019. I haven't yet submitted a 8822 (change of address form). The IRS says the following ([source)](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/us-citizens-and-resident-aliens-abroad-where-and-when-to-file-and-pay):

> If you are a U.S. citizen or resident alien residing overseas, or are in the military on duty outside the U.S., on the regular due date of your return, you are allowed an automatic 2-month extension to file your return and pay any amount due without requesting an extension.  For a calendar year return, the automatic 2-month extension is to June 15.

As always, I think the language is ambiguous. I was a US resident alien (under the substantial presence test) for 2019 but I am not, as of 2020, a US resident alien. However, I will file the 2019 tax return as a US resident alien as this is the status I had on that year. Does the two month extension apply to me?